# Express routes are conflicting

Tags: express, meanjs

I have the following express routes defined:

```
// Questions Routes 
app.route('/questions')
    .get(questions.list)
    .post(users.requiresLogin, questions.create);

app.route('/questions/:questionId')
    .get(questions.read)
    .put(users.requiresLogin, questions.hasAuthorization, questions.update)
    .delete(users.requiresLogin, questions.hasAuthorization, questions.delete);

app.route('/questions/list/:page')
            .get(questions.questionList);

app.route('/questions/count/')
            .get(questions.count);
```

Along with this callback trigger for the `questionId` route parameter:

```
app.param('questionId', questions.questionByID);
```

The expected behavior was to have `/questions/count` requests route to the count method in a controller, but it is instead being routed to the `questionByID` method and I'm seeing this error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "count" at path "_id"
...
at exports.questionByID (/path/controllers/questions.server.controller.js:137:56)
...
```

I think this appears because mongoose is trying to convert the literal "count" from the route to an ObjectId type, which would make sense if I was using the `/questions/:questionId` route but it doesn't if I'm using `/questions/count` to make the request.

These are the two relevant methods in questions.server.controller.js

```
exports.count = function (req, res) {
    console.log('attempting to count these damn questions!');
    Question.count({}, function (err, count) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            console.log(count);
            res.jsonp(count);
        }
    });
};

/**
 * Question middleware
 */
exports.questionByID = function (req, res, next, id) {
    Question.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, question) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!question) return next(new Error('Failed to load Question ' + id));
        req.question = question;
        next();
    });
};
```

I've fixed it by setting the route to:

```
app.route('/questionscount')
            .get(questions.count);
```

But it looks bad and I don't want to do it like that, does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hum.. aren't you passing a param in your call? The reason I am asking is because app.param defines a middleware to be executed before any other middleware that uses that parameter.

Comment: I'm not passing any parameters to the `/questions/count` call, that is why I don't understand why the middleware is being called, as if it was somehow being interpreted as a `/questions/:questionId` call.

Comment: can you post the code in `questions.server.controller.js`

Comment: I just added the relevant methods, please let me know if you need to see anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since express evaluates the routes in addition order, you should put the more specific routes first. In your example it just evaluates "count" as the questionId parameter because it matches the expression.

If you put the app.route('/questions/count/') route before the
app.route('/questions/:questionId') it should work.

Comment: This solves the routing issue, but I don't understand the reason, since the route parameter is called questionId instead of count.

Comment: Response updated, please check if it fulfills your thirst of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

If count and question_id have diffirence you can put  Regex to route for distinguish them